# String Object to Json in java

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a Strig variable.
**String name = "xyz";**
I want to convert it to json object
**{"name" : "xyz"}**

I am currently doing it by putting the name in the map and converting map to json.

```
Map<String, String > map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("name", name);
new Gson().toJson(map);;
```

Is there better way to do it?

Comment: you want to convert only one String variable to JSON object  or you want to convert multiple String variables?

Comment: Hi, want to convert only one variable.

Answer (score 1):

You should create an Class `Name`. So it will automatically create mapping for you:

**Sample Code:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Name name = new Name();
    name.setName("xyz");
    System.out.println(new Gson().toJson(name));
  }
```

**Output:** {"name":"xyz"}

**Name Class:**

```
public class Name {

  private String name;

  /**
   * @return the name
   */
  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  /**
   * @param name
   *          the name to set
   */
  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ObjectMapper from com.fasterxml.jackson as

```
  public static String getString(Object object) {
        try {
            //Object to JSON in String
            return objectMapper.writeValueAsString(object);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.error("Exception ", e);
            return "";
        }
    }
```

Comment: There is no major advantage in general to using Jackson over Gson.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a JSON object of any complexity, you should create a POJO to hold it for you as suggested by @notescrew. If this is a one-off (for example, in some Web controllers that return basic status information) and you are on at least Java 9, you can simplify it by using an inline map:

```
gson.toJson(Map.of("name", name));
```

Note that most frameworks (client and server) will take care of serializing to JSON for you, so in most cases you can simply pass or return the `Map` directly.